# Fetching data with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-requests

I have a function posting to a server (AWS Lambda) to perform OCR of an base64 image:

```
def image_to_text(image64):
    url = base_url + 'text-to-image'
    data = json.dumps({'image64': image64})
    r = requests.post(url, data)
    r.raise_for_status()
    return r.json()['text'].encode('utf-8')
```

The function works: `image_to_text('some long string')` will return a proper response.

**Problem:** Using `image_to_text` in parallel (multi-process) makes the application halt (without warnings or errors) at `r = request.post(url, data)`

Example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

p = mp.Pool(cpu_count())
p.map(image_to_text, ('A long string',
                      'Another long string'))
p.terminate()
```

**Question:** Why is my application halting and how can I use `multiprocessing` to fetch data with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)?

Answer (score 1):

Your application probably is not halting but it's slowing down significantly due to the large amount of data you are transferring through the `Pool`. What you perceive as a "halt" is actually big IPC overhead.

From the `multiprocessing` [programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines).

> Avoid shared state
>
> As far as possible one should try to avoid shifting large amounts of data between processes.

The `Pool` relies on an internal pipe to transfer the data to the workers which will execute your `image_to_text` function. This pipe becomes a bottleneck if the amount of data which needs to be delivered is huge. In your case, you are sending the data back and forth doubling the amount of bytes which need to be serialized and shipped.

I'd recommend you to dump the data to temporary files and send to `image_to_text` the file names only. The `image_to_text` will open and read the data from the files autonomously. You will notice your logic becoming significantly faster and more robust as well.